# Divide a list of tensors by a list of scalars in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Is there a handy way to divide a list of tensors by a list of scalars? I'm trying to do something similar to the following, but get the indicated error on the last line:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
# '1.13.1'
import numpy as np
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random([10, 3, 4])).batch(5, drop_remainder=True)
i = ds1.make_one_shot_iterator()
n = i.get_next()
n.shape
# TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(3), Dimension(4)])
var = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=np.float64)
op = n/var
# Traceback ....
# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 5 for 'truediv' (op: 'RealDiv') with input shapes: [5,3,4], [5].
```

My desired result is a list of tensors of shape [5, 3, 4] where the entries in the first are divided by 1, in the second by 2, in the third by 3, and so on. (The values 1-5 are standing in for computed values in my actual code.)

I'm pretty sure that the answer is going to be something easy, but I can't find the right set of search keywords to get SO or Google to cooperate.

Comment: The entries in the first what are divided by 1?

Comment: Do you mean to reshape `var` from `5` to `(5, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by a commenter, reshaping `var` works:

```
op = n/tf.reshape(var, (5, 1, 1))
```

This yields the expected result. Notionally, I was originally asking too much in the way of shape inference from Tensorflow.